# ASP.NET BC30198 error in included aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my aspx page say `Parent.aspx`, we access a `protected` variable defined in code behind.
**eg: Parent.aspx**

```
 <div id="rp_chat_btn_container" class="grid-4 chat-btn-container <%=isChatBtnOnRight ? "btn--rearrange" : "" %>">
```

This works absolutely fine. Now in the aspx page, I include another aspx page say `child.aspx`. In the I access the same variable.

**Parent.aspx**

```
 <!-- #include file=/used/Child.aspx -->
```

**Child.aspx**

```
  <div class="grid-4 chat-btn-container contact-seller-chat  <%=isChatBtnOnRight ? "btn--rearrange" : "" %>">
```

When I am building in Release Mode. I am getting following error:

> Child.aspx(108): error BC30198: ')' expected. [D:\JenkinsUtilities\Feature_Testing\codecheckout\Organisation\Organisation.UI.csproj]

There are no error showing in `Parent.aspx`. I want to access the same protected variable in the included aspx page(Child.aspx)

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to achieve by including child page inside parent page? May be you can achieve same functionality using user control(ascx) and place it on the parent page.

Comment: actually the child page is used for reusability

Comment: It is better to create a user control and then place it on parent aspx page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx

Comment: @Manya Only use one backtick when formatting code, not two.

Comment: Since not provided. I can only say, check line 108 and around it in Child.aspx for missing ")".

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt that your error is due to your aspx page's declaration. `error BC30198` usually comes because of syntax error in any used function. Check carefully from where your aspx page is calling .cs code. If you are using any inbuilt function, double check syntax of function with your target framework. Some functions have deprecated syntax in newer version of .net framework.